# Phantom top margin on float left

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little trouble with floating my elements. I have some phantom `margin` that has appeared on my 3rd col element; as seen in the image below;

[image]

I have tried adding; `box-sizing: border-box;` but this doesn't help either. Is there something I am missing?

**Code**

```css
#f-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  background: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<section class="ctre s-f">
  <div id="t-wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="MGI Technology logo." width="20%"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h3 class="f-h">Related Links</h3><br/>
        <ul>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">About us</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Products</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">News</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Recycle</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Site map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="style-two"/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h3 class="f-h">Social</h3><br/>
        <ul>
          <li class="f-ico"><img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="" width="100%" /></li>
          <li class="f-ico"><img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="" width="100%" /></li>
          <li class="f-ico"><img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="" width="100%" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col f-txt">
        <h3 class="f-h">Find Us</h3><br/>
        MGI Technology<br/>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" class="f-btn">MAP</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any assistance I can get with this would be greatly appreciated...

**Update:** Have now tried `vertical-align:top;` and removed `float:left`. Issue persists.

Temporary Live [Example](http://www.crosfield.org.uk/drupa2016/p-sugoi/index.php)

Comment: which browser? works fine in chrome..

Comment: Oh yeah, works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Er... Works fine in FF too: http://i.imgur.com/IQx4rrC.png

Comment: Works fine on FF, IE 10, and Chrome.

Comment: Please see question for temporary live link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your snippet is not showing any issue but anyhow, but it seems that's due to by default `inline-block` is `vertical-align:baseline`, so you must set  to `vertical-align:top`

plus remove unnecessary `float:left`

```css
#f-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  background: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<section class="ctre s-f">
  <div id="t-wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="MGI Technology logo." width="20%"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h3 class="f-h">Related Links</h3><br/>
        <ul>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">About us</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Products</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">News</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Recycle</a></li>
          <li class="f-lnk"><a href="">Site map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="style-two"/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h3 class="f-h">Social</h3><br/>
        <ul>
          <li class="f-ico"><img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="" width="100%" /></li>
          <li class="f-ico"><img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="" width="100%" /></li>
          <li class="f-ico"><img src="img-bin/mgi-logo.png" alt="" width="100%" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col f-txt">
        <h3 class="f-h">Find Us</h3><br/>
        MGI Technology<br/>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" class="f-btn">MAP</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**UPDATE**:

Looking at your live site, the issue is that the other `col` has another class `f-txt` which has a property `font-size:8pt` and with that, change the height of the column.

So either you apply the same class to the first `.col` or remove that property

Comment: I'm not at the computer now.. I'll be in a few minutes